# transform-origin properties changed several time

Tags: javascript, css, transform, scaletransform, css-transforms

I need to be able to scale a div several times with the possibility to change origin.

Please have a look at : http://jsfiddle.net/croydufixe/vdXM7/ (see full code below)

When this fiddle is run, a gray square is shown with a grid of red lines dividing the square in 4 x 4 .

A red mark is positioned to the "origin" of the next transform.

On top of the frame you can see two buttons '+' and '-' to scale the gray square by a factor increased (or decreased) by 0.5

Now, please use the following steps :

1. click the + button : the gray square is scaled by 1+0.5 using the red mark as origin
2. reposition the red mark by clicking to 25% 25% of the gray square
3. click the + button again : the gray square is scaled (1+0.5+0.5) ***but the origin of this scale is the top left corner of the gray square not the red mark***
4. clik '+' again : gray square is scaled (1+0.5+0.5+0.5) using the red mark as origin

I do not understand the origin used at step 3 (top/left and not 25%/25%)

Thank for your help.

Full code :

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
        var lastScale=1;
        var originModified = false;

        function drawCanvas()
            {
            var canevas=document.getElementById("canvas");
            var ctx = canevas.getContext("2d");
            var e=document.getElementById("canvas");
            var largeur = e.offsetWidth;
            var hauteur = e.offsetHeight;
            for( var x=0; x<largeur; x+=largeur/4 )
                {
                ctx.moveTo( x, 0 );
                ctx.lineTo( x, hauteur );
                }
            for( var y=0; y<hauteur; y+=hauteur/4 )
                {
                ctx.moveTo( 0, y );
                ctx.lineTo( largeur, y );
                }
            ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
            ctx.stroke();
            }
        function init( )
            {
            lastScale=1;
            originModified=false;
            var e = document.getElementById( "origin" );
            }
        function incrementalScale( increment )
            {
            var e=document.getElementById("a");
            var eOrigin = document.getElementById("origin");
            //  
            var targetOriginX = eOrigin.offsetLeft;
            var targetOriginY = eOrigin.offsetTop;
            e.style.transformOrigin = targetOriginX + "px " + targetOriginY + "px 0px";
            lastScale += increment;
            var transform = "scale(" + lastScale + ")";
            e.style.transform = transform;
            originModified = false;
            }
        function setOrigin(event)
            {
            if( originModified )
                {
                alert( 'origin already modified : please do a scale');
                return;
                }
            var eOrigin=document.getElementById("origin");
            var ee = document.getElementById("a");
            var deltaX = eOrigin.offsetLeft - ( event.clientX - ee.offsetLeft );
            eOrigin.style.left = ( eOrigin.offsetLeft - deltaX / lastScale ) + "px";
            var deltaY = eOrigin.offsetTop - ( event.clientY - ee.offsetTop );
            eOrigin.style.top = ( eOrigin.offsetTop - deltaY / lastScale ) + "px";
            originModified = true;
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="drawCanvas();init();">
    <div>
        scale <input type="button" onclick="incrementalScale(+0.5)" value="+">
        <input type="button" onclick="incrementalScale(-0.5)" value="-">
    </div>
    <div id="a" style="position:relative;top:400px;left:400px;border:1 px solid red;background-color:#DDD;width:200px;height:200px"
        onmousedown="setOrigin(event);">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="200px" height="200px"></canvas>
        <div id="origin" style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:100px;width:5px;height:5px;background-color:red">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```